# Use default value of wp_customizer in theme_mod output?

Tags: theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

Is there a way to output the default value of a `wp_customize` text field type using the `echo get_theme_mod ();` without actually going in the Theme Customizer, modifying something and then saving it?

I just read on another [stackexchange question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111257/get-theme-mod-returns-nothing) that the `get_theme_mod` will only show something after you save it in Theme Customizer. Not being able to output the default value of a `wp_customize` setting seems to defy the purpose of using a default value.

So, back to the question: is there a way to automatically display the default value of a `wp_customize` setting in front-end?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90942/issue-with-get-theme-mod-returning-a-blank-value-instead-of-the-saved-value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly not - all your customize controls are hooked onto `customize_register`, so they'll only ever come into play when customising the theme for the first time.

[`get_theme_mod()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) takes a second argument for a "default" value - yes, it means two instances of data in your code, but it's a half-solution.

I guess a more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach would be a coupling of globals & helper functions:

```
$my_theme_defaults = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boo',
);

function my_theme_customize( $wp_customize ) {
    global $my_theme_defaults;

    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'foo',
        array(
            'default' => $my_theme_defaults['foo'],
        )
    );  
}

function my_theme_mod( $name ) {
    global $my_theme_defaults;

    echo get_theme_mod( $name, $my_theme_defaults[ $name ] );
}
```

Comment: That would mean you'll have `$my_theme_defaults` as global variable, and also put side effects within a file that should contains only functions.

Comment: I'm just demonstrating the concept. You could use an array constant (PHP 5.6+) or a class (properties & methods), or you could refactor `my_theme_mod` to encapsulate the defaults & a second parameter flag for passing them straight back.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can output a default value. The correct way is to set a default for your mod like this:

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'MOD_ID', 'YOUR DEFAULT OUTPUT' );
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It actually does answer the question. Default values setup in a wp_customize are static so you simply enter the same default value in your get_theme_mod function second argument as you would when registering the setting.