# Why does get_theme_mod return blank (or default value) but get_option returns saved value?

Tags: theme-customizer, options, get-theme-mod

Why does `get_theme_mod` return blank (or the default value if specified) but `get_option` returns the correct (saved) value?

I have a colour picker in the customizer `color-primary` which functions correctly and saves selected value to the database, however, `get_theme_mod` returns blank while `get_option` returns the saved value.

```
echo get_option('color-primary'); //returns saved value
echo get_theme_mod('color-primary'); // returns blank
echo get_theme_mod('color-primary', '#fafafa'); // returns default value
```

Comment: You mentioned above that you have a colorpicker in the customizer... Are you sure that colorpicker uses theme_mods to save its value and not options? 'Cause if it uses options, it makes perfect sense that using `get_theme_mod` returns blank while `get_option` returns the value.
Since `get_option` returns the value, your setting is saved as an option. `get_theme_mod` will never work for that...

Comment: @Aristeides Thank you! I'd somehow snook a `'type' => 'option'` into the code - now works as expected.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90942/issue-with-get-theme-mod-returning-a-blank-value-instead-of-the-saved-value

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143789/use-default-value-of-wp-customizer-in-theme-mod-output

Answer (score 2):

This is original code from wordpress:

```
function get_theme_mods()
{
    $theme_slug = get_option('stylesheet');
    $mods = get_option("theme_mods_$theme_slug");
    if (false === $mods)
    {
        $theme_name = get_option('current_theme');
        if (false === $theme_name)
            $theme_name = wp_get_theme()->get('Name');
        $mods = get_option("mods_$theme_name"); // Deprecated location.
        if (is_admin() && false !== $mods)
        {
            update_option("theme_mods_$theme_slug", $mods);
            delete_option("mods_$theme_name");
        }
    }

    return $mods;
}

function get_theme_mods()
{
    $theme_slug = get_option('stylesheet');
    $mods = get_option("theme_mods_$theme_slug");
    if (false === $mods)
    {
        $theme_name = get_option('current_theme');
        if (false === $theme_name)
            $theme_name = wp_get_theme()->get('Name');
        $mods = get_option("mods_$theme_name"); // Deprecated location.
        if (is_admin() && false !== $mods)
        {
            update_option("theme_mods_$theme_slug", $mods);
            delete_option("mods_$theme_name");
        }
    }

    return $mods;
}
```

As you can see `get_theme_mods` uses `get_option`, but it does not use your key that you provided to save your data with, instead it uses your theme name as a key to fetch or save your theme data. Now if you fetch data with `get_theme_mod()` it will first `get_option("theme_mods_$yourthemename")` and then it parses the returned value where your saved theme options actually are.