# get_theme_mod not working

Tags: theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

For some reason I cannot output the color. Everything works, but `text_color` just doesn't want to output its value.

What is going wrong?

Back end code (functions.php):

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('text_color', array(
    'default'           => '#fff',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    'type'           => 'option',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'text_color', array(
    'label'    => __('Text color', 'pc'),
    'section'  => 'colors',
    'settings' => 'text_color',
)));
```

Front end code:

```
if(!empty(get_theme_mod( 'text_color' ))) {
?>
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color:<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'text_color' ); ?>
}
<?php
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, except that there's a missing semicolon before the closing bracket of the css statement. Could you be a bit more specific about where the problem occurs?

Comment: I had a similar problem - try removing `'type' => 'option'` - see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222245/why-does-get-theme-mod-return-blank-or-default-value-but-get-option-returns-sa#comment326332_222245

Answer (score 2):

The `'type'=>'option'` parameter is not required for the colour picker, instead use:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('text_color', array(
    'default'           => '#fff',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
));
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
type => option
```

use

```
get_option( 'text_color' )
```

and

```
type => theme_mod (default)
```

use

```
get_theme_mod( 'text_color' )
```

More here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting

Answer (score -1):

if you are using this

```
add_setting('text_color'...
```

instead of

```
add_setting('themename_theme['text_color'] ....
```

you should retrieve data by

```
get_option('text_color');
```